# finding missing coordinates (lat/lon) in python

Tags: python, gps, coordinates

I have list of route coordinates but there are some parts of the route, where no gps data were available. Assuming I was driving with a linear velocity, is there helpful library to locate the approximation my coordinates every second?

Edit: I need to locate the points on the road.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you assuming to follow a path (such as a road or trail indicated on a map) or just draw a straight line between coordinates? The latter seems like simple math?

Comment: Yeah. just do simple interpolation independently on both coordinates. I doubt you have huge distances (between points) where you should use spheric coordinates. To do a better job, you need to look some statistics (e.g. to correct noise, find out,layers, etc.)

Comment: unfortunately, it's not just simple interpolation, The lost distance is around 7 km (driving distance inside a tunnel) so I need to locate the points on the road.